# EJB scheduler service stateless vs singleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, scheduler, ejb-3.1

My application has a scheduler which needs to run every 10 sec to pull the new records from the database. I have implemented ejb scheduler service by following [this guide](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers) which is running fine. There is no client to hit() method, it should run as a scheduler only.

Singleton only approach,

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class DataFetcherService {
    @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=true)
    public void hit() {
           //do some stuff
           fetchData();
    }
    public void fetchData() {
          //Fetch new records from the database through DAO objects
    }
}
```

Is there any difference if i replace @singleton with @stateless? Please suggest

Updates: Stateless approach,

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class DataFetcherService {
    @EJB
    DataFetcherBean dataFetcherBean;
    @Schedule(second="*/10", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=true)
    public void hit() {
           dataFetcherBean.fetchData();
    }  
}
@Stateless
public class DataFetcherBean { 
    public void fetchData() {
          //Fetch new records from the database through DAO objects
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely clear on your question, but if I understand you correctly you could approach this two ways. If you want to you can inject your `EntityManager` in your `@Singleton` and then put your JPA related biz logic in methods in the `@Singleton` which would be called by hit() and any other methods that these other clients would be calling. In that case client access and scheduled access would all happen in a synchronized fashion. Not great for performance but I guess that's your architecture.

The other option would be to more loosely couple things by placing this data fetch biz logic in its own `@Stateless` EJB and inject that EJB into your `@Singleton`. Your `@Singleton` could then call methods on this EJB from hit() and any other methods. Because the default container managed concurrency of `@Singleton` is `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` you will effectively serialize all access of your injected EJB (so long as it all goes through the singleton). This design makes things more loosely coupled, but increases the number of classes involved and adds a stateless EJB which will be pooled thus using more resources. Those are some of the trade offs.

If you choose the 1st option and you ever need non-synchronized execution of said biz logic you would need to refactor things to using a `@Stateless` EJB.

One more thing to consider. If you decide to go with the `@Singleton` only approach you have to be careful if you need to have one of its methods call another one of its methods. In this case you will not be able to use CMC (container managed concurrency) but instead you will have use `ConcurrenyManagementType.Bean` and handle synchronization yourself.

Updated per new comments from the OP:

@Hello - If you replace `@Singleton` with `@Stateless` you will also loose `@Startup` as its only available on `@Singleton` beans. That may or may not matter to you, though it will not have any bearing on the `@Schedule` method as that will get seen and 'set up' at application deployment time.

You need to invoke `fetchData();` using the bean's proxy, either gotten from an injected `SessionContext` resource or through self injection. The way you are doing it now side steps the container including the TX the container started when the scheduled method was invoked. Sometimes that matter sometimes it doesn't but can lead to subtle bugs which is why its usually best to ensure you access 'local' methods via the proxy.

Lastly, if you use the above approach with `@Singleton` you are going to need to switch to bean managed concurrency because the container does not handle this type of method access to `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` methods in a re-entrant fashion and will give you an error (at least this is the behavior I have seen in JavaEE6 on Glasfish).

Comment: `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)`.

Comment: NBW, i have updated the post. can you plz look at it? I have 2 qns: Is there any issue with the above approach (Container management type)? Can we replace singleton with stateless annotation?

Comment: @Hello - Updated my response for your questions and changed.

Comment: I get a compile-time error with a string literal in EJB 3.2 / Java EE 7.

Comment: @Tiny - Fair enough, I've updated my post to fix that. Thanks.

Comment: @NBW, Assuming the code/design which i posted is Singleton only approach mentioned by you. You said i cannot use CMC with this approach, does it mean calling fetchData() from hit() method? I am also updating the original post with stateless ejb approach. Is this what you were referring? ANd what is the advantage with accessing local methods via the bean's proxy? Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of differences between using @Singleton and @Stateless for your scheduled service:

- If you use an @Stateless then the bean instance that executes the annotated method will be completely autonomous and cannot be referenced by the rest of your application. The container will create the timer at deployment time and invoke the callback according to the schedule. If you try to inject an instance of this bean then you will get another copy of it (without a running schedule).
- If you use an @Singleton bean then you can inject it and change it's state, possibly influencing the behaviour of the timer callback.